# Mod-Rewrite - Using usual path to css/js/images

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I have some code to make `www.domain.com/state/statename/folder/index.php?name=name` to `statename.name.domain.com`. These are my codes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule !^state/ /state/%1/folder/index.php?name=%2&page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

The problem is now I have to use full url to link my css, js and image files. 
Also, one of the plugins in my code (AjaxLoader) Couldn't use full url to load a page in a div. Relative path such as `(path/filepath.ext)` does not work.

So, is there anyway to use usual path `(path/filepath.ext)`?

Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule !^state/ /state/%1/folder/index.php?name=%2&page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

If that doesn't work then try [`base tag`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.4) like:

```
<BASE href="http://statename.name.domain.com/">
```

Comment: Nice to meet you again in here. The first one does the same as the above code. It still need to use http link. The second solution(BASE) works for css,images and js but not for AjaxLoader URL. In firefox developer tools, it shows the request as OPTIONS instead of GET. The response is positive (200 OK)

Comment: So if BASE tag worked for css, js, images then bulk of your problem is solved. You just need to proiude full path for `AjaxLoader`

Comment: Also can you tell me full URL what `AjaxLoader` is requesting?

Comment: As the file that Ajaxloader need to request in ON the same folder. So I just put `file.php'. When I put the full url, it returns GET (200 OK) but it doesnt show anything.

Comment: When you say same folder does it mean DOCUMENT_ROOT for `statename.name.domain.com` ?

Comment: Nope, it's in `www.domain.com/state/statename/folder/` where `statename.name.domain.com` is redirected

Comment: Nope, same thing happens. I think it's a problem with AjaxLoader maybe I can find another loader to work with

Comment: Hmm ok, try debugging this whole page load + AJAX call in Firebug as see what you get.

Comment: I got **red-colored** 200 ok response which is not okay actually.

Comment: Hmm I see. I'm not a UI person but wonder why a 200 will cause problems? Going offline now, will check again in the morning.

Comment: For the AJAX request can you copy/paste **full URL** that was sent to server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39042/discussion-between-redzwan-latif-and-anubhava)